# Disable resize event on custom calendar event, is it possible?

Tags: vaadin

I have problem with vaadin calendar add on.

Is it possible to create custom calendar event which will have disabled resize and drag event?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure ,But try it .
In `ScheduleView.java` File

Find  `cal.setDropHandler(new DropHandler() {`

and replace that with following

```
 cal.setDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
            return false;
          }

        public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion() {
            return AcceptAll.get();
        }

    });
```

same as for `BasicEventMoveHandler`

```
 cal.setHandler(new BasicEventMoveHandler() {
            @Override
            public void eventMove(MoveEvent event) {
                  return false;
                }
            }

            protected void setDates(MovieEvent event, Date start, Date end) {
                event.start = start;
                event.end = end;
            }
        });
```

Same For `BasicEventResizeHandler`

```
cal.setHandler(new BasicEventResizeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void eventResize(EventResize event) {
                   return false;
            }
        });
```

## To run

Run the Maven install target and deploy the resulting WAR-file to your server.